# Creating and Transposing Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm hoping to load values in a range to an array and transpose that array to another location (different workbook)

I am using the below forum post to get an idea of how to do it:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/629320-application-transpose-visual-basic-applications-array.html

Below is the code I am working with now, and I'm getting the 1004 object defined error. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

I did find that the code works if I do not Set tRangeArray and instead do `Sheets("sheet1").Range("C12:C19).Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)`, but I'm not sure why that's different from my code.

```
Sub copy_data()
Dim cRange As Range, aRange As Range, tRange1 As Range, wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As
Workbook
Dim MyArray() As Variant, tRangeArray As Range

Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook

MyArray = Range("E12:L12")
Set tRangeArray = wbk1.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C12:C19")

Sheets("sheet1").Range(tRangeArray).Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
```

Comment: `tRangeArray.Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, just use:

```
tRangeArray.Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
```

`Sheets("sheet1").Range(tRangeArray).Value` not working, because `Range` accepts either single parameter - string with range *address* (not range itself): `Range(addr)`, either two parameters - top left and bottom right cells: `Range(cell_1,cell_2)`

Answer (score 2):

Similar, but using Resize and Ubound:

```
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(myarray), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(myarray)
```