# Transpose loop in VBA

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I am attempting to transpose values into new rows on the same sheet. Can someone help me with the proper vba code to be the output I am looking for?

Given:

```
Col1    Col2  Col3  Col4
Title1  A     B     C
Title2  D     E     
Title3  F
title4  G     H
```

Wanted:

```
Col1    Col2  Col3  Col4
Title1  A          
Title1  B   
Title1  C
Title2  D     
Title2  E
Title3  F
Title4  G
Title4  H
```

Comment: Please clarify the current layout and the desired one.  Using fixed-width text might help.

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174916/transpose-a-range-in-vba and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456328/creating-and-transposing-array-in-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quick macro should make short work of the process.

```
Sub transpose_in_place()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            For cl = .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 3 Step -1
                If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then
                    .Rows(rw + 1).Insert
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 2) = .Cells(rw, cl).Value2
                    .Cells(rw, cl).Clear
                End If
            Next cl
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

As the name suggests, it will perform the transposition in place so perhaps you should test it on a copy of your actual data before committing to the full process.

[image]